# Instruments says there is a memory leak in this method, but I can't figure out where

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, instruments

According to instrument there is memory leak at these lines

```
    cat.catName = (catName)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:catName]:@"";
    NSData *dataForCachedImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 2) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 2)];           
    cat.catThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:dataForCachedImage];
    [dataForCachedImage release];
```

in the following code.

I have also statically analyzed the code.. shows no issue in this file.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getAllItems{
NSMutableArray *items = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER by sort";

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

int sqlresult = sqlite3_prepare(database, sql, -1, &statement, nil);

if (sqlresult == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        Category *cat = [[Category alloc] init];

        char *catName = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);

        cat.catID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        cat.catName = (catName)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:catName]:@"";
        NSData *dataForCachedImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 2) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 2)];           
        cat.catThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:dataForCachedImage];
        [dataForCachedImage release];
        cat.catLock = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 3);
        cat.sort = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
        cat.total = [self totalSMS:cat.catID];

        [items addObject:cat];

        [cat release];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"problem with the database");
    NSLog(@"%d",sqlresult);
}
return items;}
```

can someone point out?
Thanks

Comment: if you break out the standard C sqlite3 calls and analyze, I think you will see pretty clearly what is going on. Like: `const void * blob = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 2);`

Comment: But that doesn't mean you should send them to sqlite3_free() sqlite 3 handles that in the background.

Comment: @Grady: I am still confused... I tried using the code you suggested, but I still get the same old 380 number of leaks!...  can you please elaborate... newbie here!

Comment: I think that it is a leak in the sense that you don't have a valid pointer to the memory anymore, but it isn't really a leak in that sqlite3 is handling the memory for you. when you close the DB (actually finalize should clean it up too.), it should all be taken care of. you can verify to make sure that the memory doesn't actually climb after you do that over and over.

Comment: Thx for the inputs man... but it is still getting over me... I think it would be better off to store the path to images instead of blob in sqlite, and leave this thing all together. What do u say? I will try it in few hours from now, and let you know.

Comment: ok.. resolved it!... the problem was that the catThumb was not released in Category class. thats it!, no other modification required... anyways, thx again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. resolved it!... the problem was that the catThumb was not released in Category class. thats it!, no other modification required... anyways, thx everybody!

Answer (score 1):

In the first sample of code you aren't releasing `dataForCachedImage`. You can either change it to

```
cat.catName = (catName)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:catName]:@"";
NSData *dataForCachedImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 2) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 2)];           
cat.catThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:dataForCachedImage];
[dataForCachedImage release];
```

or

```
cat.catName = (catName)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:catName]:@"";
NSData *dataForCachedImage = [[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 2) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 2)] autorelease];           
cat.catThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:dataForCachedImage];
```

Comment: in that first sample.. I just wrote the code that instrument highlights in the method.... I am using the whole method in the second sample... edited post to reflact the same